# Install Peoplesoft and connect to existing Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

Is there a guide that can help me install PeopleSoft, PeopleTools, Tuxedo, Weblogic etc. and connect it to an existing Oracle DB configured for CS?

I'm fine with doing the setup from scratch, but how do I skip the DB creation and just configure the rest to connect to a DB called CSSND2.

Can anyone help with some steps?

The guide I followed is:
http://psst0101.digitaleagle.net/step-by-step/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has official installation guide for every PeopleTools version.
This is the one for the latest version, 8.55: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E68526_01/psft/acrobat/PeopleTools_855_Installation_for_Oracle_122015.pdf
If your version is lower, google 'PeopleTools Installation guide ', replacing  by your version.

Install all the software on your server, add the details of your schema/database  to the tnsnames.ora file, then you can add the App server domain, Process Scheduler domain and web domain. See the guide for details on installation and configuration